# No module named Alchemy API

Tags: python, alchemyapi

I am trying to run Alchemy API on my computer for python 2.7. This is the file:

```
AlchemyAPI.py-2.5
```

I have kept it in the same file as the Code:

```
# Load the AlchemyAPI module code.
import AlchemyAPI


# Create an AlchemyAPI object.
alchemyObj = AlchemyAPI.AlchemyAPI()


# Load the API key from disk.
alchemyObj.loadAPIKey("api_key.txt")


# Extract a ranked list of named entities from a web URL.
result = alchemyObj.URLGetRankedNamedEntities("http://www.techcrunch.com/");
print (result)


# Extract a ranked list of named entities from a text string.
result = alchemyObj.TextGetRankedNamedEntities("Hello my name is Bob.  I am speaking to you at this very moment.  Are you listening to me, Bob?");
print (result)


# Load a HTML document to analyze.
htmlFileHandle = open("data/example.html", 'r')
htmlFile = htmlFileHandle.read()
htmlFileHandle.close()


# Extract a ranked list of named entities from a HTML document.
result = alchemyObj.HTMLGetRankedNamedEntities(htmlFile, "http://www.test.com/");
print (result)
```

This is the standard code and gives the error i have mentioned in the heading. As required by README i have copied the AlchemyAPI.py-2.5 into the same directory. Im not sure how py-2.5 file works.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the -2.5 from the file extension, just save it as "AlchemyAPI.py"

Also, if you are running python 2.7, is there a reason you are using the python 2.5 version file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you vizit that [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AlchemyAPI/1.0)?
It contains all information about AlchemyAPI module.